# Neural Network weights and cost changing but not it's accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am training a neural network, and starting with random weights. After training, the weights changed but yet the accuracy of the neural network is the same as the starting weights. And don't matter how I change the architecture of the network. The number of nodes in hidden layers, number of iterations and the number of features (using PCA for dimension reduction) It's comes up with the same accuracy as the start. Could this because of low number of examples with respect to number of features? (I have 675 examples and 9000 features). Or is this because of something else? Also I tried the same data set with logistic regression, and it was able to accuracy up to 64%, not great it's much better than the 50% I am getting before and after training with neural networks.

Answer (score 3):

In general, your training examples should outnumber your features by orders of magnitude, not the other way around. That's going to hurt you unless your PCA brings things down quite a lot.

You did remember to normalize your features, right? That's usually taken care of in PCA, but sometimes you have to normalize first, depending on the software you're using.

Other than that, you didn't mention changing the learning rates, using adaptive learning rates, or using the momentum term, so I'm going to recommend you look into those. Additionally, there are more weight update algorithms than just plain old backprop. The [Levenberg-Marquardt Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm) might be worth a try. Your implementation might already have this, assuming you aren't writing it yourself.

Some form of early stopping might be useful as well.

You didn't mention whether you're trying to do classification or regression. If you're doing classification, make sure the activation function on your output nodes matches the type of class labels you're using. Logsig has a range of 0 to 1, while Tansig is -1 to 1. If you're doing regression, ensure the outputs have linear activation, or at least that the range of possible outputs matches your training examples.

Comment: Alot of info there. PCA seems to bring down the number of features to the number of examples. And it is classification. I am using fmincg in matlab, which I believe have an adaptive learning rate. And I did normalise it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing classification, the problem might be in your labels.

I had similar problem while training a neural network in Octave. Accuracy was about 50%. I had two labels 0 and 1. My accuracy was low, because octave starts indexing from 1 not 0. You might want to look into your labels.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the classification accuracy, depends on the dataset. All artificial intelligence methods try to separate data in a vector space. However, the data might not be separable in the first place, and in some cases 64% might be very close to the best possible result. What kind of dataset are you using (is it one of the well-known benchmarks, or some specific problem you are trying to solve??)

Second, the fact that the weights change does not necessarily mean that the network is being trained. After training, you should not check if the weights change, but if the total square error is reduced. If it hasn't reduced significantly, your network might have not been trained at all. In your case, if the accuracy remains 50% after the training (I suppose you are talking about a two-class problem), most probably the method does not work at all. You should first try it on a much simpler dataset, to check that it works.

Moreover:

- 9000 features are too many, if you are trying to train a multi-layer perceptron. You probably need SVMs for such a complex problem.
- The number of instances is, most likely, too small for such a problem (however, if the patterns between the two classes are too far in problem space)